# How do I determine at runtime whether the style applied to an object is the default style?

Tags: wpf, styles

I want to be able to apply a style at runtime to an object **ONLY** if the current style is the default style. I don't want to override any user defined styles. Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you can do it this way:

```
DependencyPropertyHelper.GetValueSource(
    someControl, FrameworkElement.StyleProperty).BaseValueSource 
    == BaseValueSource.Default;
```

You can wrap that up in an extension method like this:

```
static public bool HasDefaultStyle(this FrameworkElement item)
{
    return DependencyPropertyHelper.GetValueSource(
        item, FrameworkElement.StyleProperty).BaseValueSource 
        == BaseValueSource.Default;
}
```

Then you can just call `someControl.HasDefaultStyle()`.

Also, have a look at this article:  [Default Templates in WPF](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/02/14/wpfdefaulttemplate)

Answer (score -1):

Check the DefaultStyleKeyProperty, which is a static property of any custom control.

```
string styleKeyName = DefaultStyleKeyProperty.Name;
```

Usually if there is no style associated with the control, the Name will be "DefaultStyleKey"